# Интерактивная карта

Tags: jquery, css, javascript

Добрый вечер!

Вопрос в следующем: есть интерактивная карта, но, например, Архангельская область состоит из двух частей. Как сделать чтобы при наведении выделялись обе части?
Подскажите в какую сторону копать!

http://szsi.com.ua/page/map/

Comment: Посмотрел устройство сайта, совет: чем раньше перейдете на UTF-8 или другую Unicode кодировку, тем лучше.

Comment: так там и стоит кодировка <meta charset="utf-8" />

Comment: @soledar10 а комментарии в javascript почему-то в WIN-1251.

Comment: чем вас [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) не устраивает ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Соедините два полигона в один с помощью перешейка шириной ноль.

[image: перешеек]

Соединить два полигона

Два полигона — список вершин. Допустим это два массива `p1` и `p2` длиной `n` и `m` соответственно. Чтобы построить новый нужно обойти первый, перейти на второй, обойти второй и вернуться обратно. Тогда новый полигон будет таким:

```
p1[0], ... , p1[n], /* перешеек */ p2[1], ... , p2[m], p2[1], /* развернутый перешеек */ p1[n]
```

*Примечание*: `/* перешеек */` может состоять из нуля точек.

Comment: подскажите как перешееек задать шириной ноль

Comment: взял координата одного + кординаты второго - мостик видимый

Comment: @soledar10 обновил ответ

Comment: Сделал как Вы и говорите - перешеек все равно есть(бордер), затем меняю бордер на белый цвет - почти получилось, но это сразу ограничивает использование такой карты.
также подскажите как точно определять координаты(если существует такой метод)!